# Angular 5 shared function & variable among two components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I need a global function for two separate components.
I’m loading two angular components using selectors on a main HTML page.
One has function buttons and its function has to affect content in the other component as well.

I realized this can’t be easily done… how do you guys set up shared function & variables between two angular components?
I’m trying to create a single button which can load tab contents in two separate components.
is using angular local storage a solution to store certain function and variables?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is an Ionic 3 projects using Angular 5.

Comment: If you're using Typescript, why not create a common base class, that the components can inherit from?

Comment: Why not just use a service that you inject into the components you want to use the shared function?

Comment: Cool, I will try both methods. If there's any github example or plunkr example, I'd appreciate them. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple with service.

```
export class ExampleService {

   public sharedVariable: any;

   public sharedFunction() {
       // your implementation
   }
}


export class Component1 {
    public constructor(private service: ExampleService) {
        this.service.sharedFunction();
        this.service.sharedVariable;
    }
}

export class Component2 {
    public constructor(private service: ExampleService) {
        this.service.sharedFunction();
        this.service.sharedVariable;
    }
}
```

In the case of using a common class, you will get two different references  for the `sharedVariable` and if you change the variable value in the first component it won't affect the second one, but if you use `service` the service is singleton by default in angular so you will get the same value in both components but changing the value just ones from anywhere.

```
export abstract class BaseClass {

   public sharedVariable: any;

   public sharedFunction() {
       // your implementation
   }
}


export class Component1 extends BaseClass {
    public constructor() {
        super();
        this.sharedFunction();
        this.sharedVariable;
    }
}

export class Component2 extends BaseClass {
    public constructor() {
        super();
        this.sharedFunction();
        this.sharedVariable;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this shortly!